# How can I find a package name which contains specific file?

Tags: debian, apt

Example:

- `/etc/bind/db.local` file is created by apt package `bind9` ( source: https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/bind9/filelist )
- but how to find a package which have created for example `/usr/share/dns/root.hints`?

I am looking for a universal solution to check any file path and the answer should be the package name (names if there is more then one) or reliable answer, that the file path was created by a user (i.e. not by `apt install`).

Comment: The user may be whatever service user is running `bind` though...

Comment: @Kusalananda No, I do not need an user name. I need a package name or an answer, that the file was not created by apt package.

Comment: like `dpkg-query -S FILE`? https://superuser.com/a/179354

Comment: @guest Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: It depends a bit what you mean by "created" - `dpkg-query -S` (or `dpkg -S`) will find files that are installed directly from the package archive, however there are sometimes additional files created by package installation scripts, which AFAIK it will not show.

Comment: @steeldriver Good point, I meant mainly the files that are listed like here https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/bind9/filelist - and for these the `dpkg-query -S` seems to work very well.

Comment: My point was that some files may well be created _by running_ a program rather than by installing its package. Some files may well be created by daemon accounts in this way.

Comment: etc keeper, may also be of help. However you have to install it before the other packages.